# Reshaping Python array in a particular way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, reshape

I am working on a Python code so that I can basically do this with a Numpy Array

[image]

I have a Matlab code for it, which is

```
A = [1:30]'; % Example matrix
rows = 3;

for i=1:(numel(A)-rows+1)
    B(1:rows,i)=A(i:i+rows-1,1);
end
```

or, without any loop,

```
B = conv2(A.', flip(eye(rows)));
```

`B = B(:, rows:end-rows+1);`

Can someone help me do the same in Python? Using the reshape function is not helping since I need to "mirror" the values (and not only reorganizing them).

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a NumPy array?

Comment: @miradulo yes its a NumPy array miradulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not very sexy but no for

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1,31)
b = np.arange(3).reshape(3,1)
c = b+a[:28]
```

trying to translate your matlab code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

a = np.arange(1,31).reshape(1,30)
b = np.flip(np.eye(3,28),0)
c = convolve2d(a, b)[:,2:28]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
start = 1
end = 30
b_dim = 28

a = np.arange(start, end+1)
b = np.zeros((3, b_dim))

print("a = ", a)

rows, _ = b.shape

for row in range(rows):
    data = a[row:row+b_dim]
    b[row, :] = data

print("b = ", b)
```

it prints

```
('a = ', array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]))
('b = ', array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,
         12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,
         23.,  24.,  25.,  26.,  27.,  28.],
       [  2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,  12.,
         13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,
         24.,  25.,  26.,  27.,  28.,  29.],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,
         14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.,
         25.,  26.,  27.,  28.,  29.,  30.]]))
```

Comment: that's my sloppy 8 =)

Comment: hey no worries!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for you.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(list(range(1,31)))

rows = 3

new_A = np.zeros((rows,A.size-rows+1))

for i in range(rows):
    new_A[i,:] = A[i:A.size-rows+i+1]

print (new_A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`np.ndarray.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(1, 31)
B = A.reshape((3, 10))

print(B)

[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
 [11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30]]
```